# Problem of Regex'ing images to BBCode

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I'm working on something for phpBB3 of my own, I'm trying to convert those smiles back to the oringinal smiley state, e.g.

```
:)  :(  :O  :P
```

Since the HTML of a smiley contains this:

```
/<img src=".*" alt="(.*)" title=".*">/gi
```

Replaced to:

```
$1
```

However, when I have multiple smileys, it just show the last smiley, e.g. if it was like this:

[alt text http://uimgz.com/i/R2e3H8g5D8.png](http://uimgz.com/i/R2e3H8g5D8.png)

It turns into this:

```
:twisted:
```

Which is the last smiley on the right, why hasn't it replaced and returned all of the smiley states which it should return like this:

```
:) :o :twisted:
```

The Regex seems fine, but I don't what seems to be the problem, all of the regex go through a replacement loop using a `for()` loop so that's not the problem.

**Multiple smileys HTML:**

```
<img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_smile.gif" alt=":)" title="Smile" /> <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_surprised.gif" alt=":o" title="Surprised" /> <img src="./images/smilies/icon_twisted.gif" alt=":twisted:" title="Twisted Evil" />
```

Comment: How does the html looks like when there are multiple smileys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to this and try again:

```
/<img src="[^"]*" alt="([^"]+)" title="[^"]*">/gi
```

The regex engine is usually greedy. It will try to match the longest text matching something. In your case i it matched all three links as one. What i did here was to limit the content inside the src attribute to not contain " so it will not match all the way to the third src.
It treated this as a src attribute `./images/smilies/icon_e_smile.gif" alt=":)" title="Smile" /> <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_surprised.gif" alt=":o" title="Surprised" /> <img src="./images/smilies/icon_twisted.gif`

Answer (score 1):

Use `*?` and `+?` for non-greedy matching:

```
/<img src=".*?" alt="(.+?)" title=".*?">/gi
```

What's happening in your failing example is that the first `.*` is matching all of this:

```
./images/smilies/icon_e_smile.gif" alt=":)" title="Smile" /> <img src="./images/smilies/icon_e_surprised.gif" alt=":o" title="Surprised" /> <img src="./images/smilies/icon_twisted.gif
```

which is still producing a valid match, but it's not what you want. The `?` after `*`/`+` makes the regex consume the smallest string necessary to make a successful match. Read the section "Watch Out for The Greediness!" in [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

I'd like to also add the general warning that regular expressions aren't the best tool for parsing HTML. Even my regex will break if the `src` attribute has an escaped `"` for example.